# How to find limit of $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n+ \frac{1}{k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

How to find limit of $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}{n+ \frac{1}{k}}$

Is exist method to solve this problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^{k/n}}{n+1/k}&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k/n)2^{k/n}}{(k/n)+1/n^2}\\\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k/n}-\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{(k/n)+1/n^2}
\end{align}$$

Recall that $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k/n}$ is the Riemann Sum for $\int_0^{1} 2^x\,dx$.

Furthermore we have

$$\left| \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{(k/n)+1/n^2}\right|\le \frac{2n}{n^2+1}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Of course, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome Eugene.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: Well done, Mark !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you Claude!

Answer (score 4):

Since

$$\frac{1}{n+1} \leqslant \frac{1}{n + 1/k} \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$$

we have

$$\frac{n}{n+1} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k/n} \right) \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^{k/n}}{n + 1/k} \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k/n} $$

Apply the squeeze theorem.